# Eager load nested multiple relation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have some tables:

- records
- record_relations
- identifications
- inventories
- prices

`Record` has a polymorphic relationship to relate with `Identification`, `Inventory` and `Price`. `Inventory` has a relationship with `Metric` and `Price` has a relationship with `Currency`. So...

- `Record` `hasMany` `RecordRelations` through `relations()`
- `RecordRelation` `morphTo` `Identification`, `Inventory` and `Price` through `relation()`
- `Inventory` `belongsTo` `Metric` through `metric()`
- `Price` `belongsTo` `Currency` through `currency()`

If I lazy load everything works but I need to eager load all relationships (I display them in a datatable); after trying a lot I was able to load the deepest relation:

```
$builder->with([
    'relations' => function($query) {

        $query->with('relation.metric')->where('relation_type', '=', 'App\\Inventory');

    }
]);
```

However if I add the other relations I have all relationships empty...

```
$builder->with([
    'relations' => function($query) {

        $query->with('relation');
        $query->with('relation.metric')->where('relation_type', '=', 'App\\Inventory');
        $query->with('relation.currency')->where('relation_type', '=', 'App\\Price');

    }
]);
```

It seems I can't, for some reason, "`withWhere`" more than once. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

define your relation as bellow

```
$builder->with([
    'relations' => function($query) {
        $query->addSelect('column_names');
    },
    'relation.metric' => function($query){
        $query->addSelect('column_names')->where('_condition goes here');
    },
    'relation.currency' => function($query){
        $query->addSelect('column_names')->where('_condition goes here');
    }
```

]);

replace columns_names with the names of column you want to retrieve.
and _condition with the condition you want to apply.

Comment: In order to acess `relation` I need to go through `relations.relation`, does it work this way?

Comment: No its not necessary...but if relation table is getting reference from relations table then it is required.